# new operator syntax fails

Tags: c#, nhibernate

```
    [Test]
    public void can_generate_schema()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddAssembly(typeof(Product).Assembly);
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false, false);
    }
```

I am reading a tutorial of Nhibernate and the above code is what i am given to run in a test application.

The installed VS10 doesn't seem to recognize the new operator at the last line in the function and it always reports an error of incorrect use of Execute method which needs not only 4 parameters.

Comment: `Execute method which needs not only 4 parameters` - so it is not the `new` operator that fails ...

Comment: Thanks, that's a cool explanetion

Answer (score 1):

Seems a version problem. In 2.1 there are only three parameters. No format.
Remove the last one parameter

```
new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(false, true, false);
```